# Sparkjava unable to put data into the response body

Tags: java, android, android-volley, httpresponse, spark-java

I'm trying to a client (Android) talk to our server which is using sparkjava, but running into the issue that when the client is trying to parse the body of the response `response.data` with Volley, it's getting that the response body is empty. The client is sending a [`JsonRequestObject`](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html) , which will throw a JSONException if the response's body is empty.

Here is our sparkJava controller:

```
  public static String doThis(Request request, Response response) {
        response.type("application/json");

        // If the request fails validations, then return a 400
        if (request.failsValidations()) {
            response.status(HTTP_BAD_REQUEST); // 400
            response.header("Error", "Bad request");
        } else {
            response.status(HTTP_SUCCESS); // 200
            // Put the response into the data
            String responseData = "{//someJson}"
            response.header("data", responseData);
            response.body(data);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

I'm setting the same data in the header and body, but when I look at the response received on the client, the data is only in the header and not in the body. So I was thinking that Spark's response.body() method isn't really putting the data into the response being sent back.
Is the way response.body is represented in sparkjava different from how volley views it? Or is there another way to put data into the response body from spark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in two ways:

1. Using a JSON Object

   ```
   public static Object doThis(Request request, Response response) {
       response.type("application/json");

       JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
       jo.put("data", "someData");
       return jo;
   }
   ```
2. Using a string formatted as JSON

   ```
   public static Object doThis(Request request, Response response) {
       response.type("application/json");

       return "{\"data\":\"someData\"}";
   }
   ```

The first one is better IMO because you can modify the JSON object in a much more convenient way (but you have to `import org.json.JSONObject`).

Then, on the client side, you should treat the data as JSON data type. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This worked, I don't know why spark's response.body() wasn't putting anything in the body.

Comment: @SamShih check this issue https://github.com/perwendel/spark/issues/750 . It is normal to be confused over this. This is an old issue, and a bad/misleading design IMO.

Comment: @k.liakos agreed.